# Equivalent of git ls-files in mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial

How can I see the files which are currently in my `mercurial` repository?

Since the working directory has both tracked and untracked files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`hg manifest` will list files in commits, defaulting to the first parent of the working directory. `hg status` with various flags will list files that are tracked or untracked.

Comment: Since others will search for this here, I thought I’d mention an extension I’ve written that gives Mercurial its own "ls" command: http://alastairs-place.net/projects/hglist/

Comment: @alastair That extension looks helpful, but for newer Mercurial users like me the Readme is a bit sparse on how to install / enable the extension.

Comment: @iain You install it the same way you install any Mercurial extension. See http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UsingExtensions